# Реализация авторизации

Tags: android, activity

Мне необходимо сделать авторизацию в приложении, но посредством собственного api не использую сторонние типа openid и т.д

Суть вопроса в следующим, я передаю запрос серверу с логином и паролем, он при верных данных возвращает токен который я могу потом использовать при запросах, и сохраняю его в приватное хранилище в текстовом файле.
И теперь я не знаю как реализовать переход к "главной" активности если токен уже имеется (то есть пользователь уже вошел в систему).

Сейчас у меня открывается активность с формой входа, и в `onCreate` я проверяю наличие этого файла с токеном, если он существует то кидаю пользователя посредством `startActivity` на "главную" активность, как зашедшего пользователя, но при этом я как бы на активности формы входа, и это операция с проверкой существования токена и перенаправления на другую активность будет происходить довольно часто.

Как в android'e делают такие вещи?

Comment: Вам нужно наоборот все сделать. В главной активити проверять, есть ли авторизация и если нет, то переходить к активити ввода учетных данных, иначе продолжать.

Comment: Или из фрагментов собирать

Comment: вы правильно делаете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

проверяйте наличие токена в mainactivity, если токена нет, запускайте login. для авторизации используйте [account manager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) ([пример](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/)), токен можно хранить в shared preferences.